# How to find out excel sheet formula operator using apache poi 3.6?

Tags: apache-poi

I have cell formula like C1+C2.suppose i use getcellformula()method it returns the String C1+C2. Now i want to split the String by operator and get the each cell Address separately.Is there anyway to find out the Excel formula operator and get the each cell address separately. How i do?

Please reply me...

Saravanan.p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273871/how-to-use-org-apache-poi-ss-formula-formulaparser-to-parse-the-formula/4274191#4274191) to your other question will answer this as well.

A formula `=D4+D6` when parsed via [`FormulaParser`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParser.html) gives

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D4]
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D6]
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg
```

RefPtg points to the cell reference `D4`, and `+` is `AddPtg`

Note POI uses the format of [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) i.e. it puts which puts the **operator** in the **post-fix** position.

> In Reverse Polish notation the
>   operators follow their operands; for
>   instance, to add three and four, one
>   would write "3 4 +" rather than "3 +
>   4".