# How to use org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser to parse the formula?

Tags: apache-poi

Can u give me the simple code snippt using org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.

FormulaParser class having the method parse().But it returns ptg[].i dont know where is the ptg class...
Please guide me to use formulaParse to parse the excel sheet formula...

Saravanan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Ptg[]` is a [array of tokens](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/Ptg.html) which represents the formula in the cell.

Suppose in my excel sheet I have as cell with a formula as

```
=D4+D6+D8-D11+D23+D29+D46-D49
```

Running this through a FormulaParser gives me an array which I have printed out as shown below

```
HSSFEvaluationWorkbook hssfew = HSSFEvaluationWorkbook.create(workBook);

Ptg[] ptg = FormulaParser.parse(cell1.getCellFormula(), hssfew, FormulaType.NAMEDRANGE, 0);

for (int i=0;i<ptg.length;i++){
    System.out.println (ptg[i]);
}
```

Result

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D4] 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D6] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D8] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D11] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.SubtractPtg
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D23]
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D29] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D46] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.AddPtg 
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.RefPtg [D49] 
class org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.SubtractPtg
```

As you can see this breaks down each element in the formula into the respective cell location or operator
AddPtg for `+` and SubtractPtg for    `-` operator

This is a simple example, you can try out more complex stuff

Comment: thanks jose, but how to get the operator that is appeared in the formula... for example i want + + - something like that... please help me get this...

Comment: as i explained in the answer, *+* is presented as *AddPtg* so you know that meant *+*. Similarly for *-*

Comment: try out my example code with your own cell formula, and see the results.

Comment: and I have explained the Reverse Polish Notation poi uses in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265118/how-to-find-out-excel-sheet-formula-operator-using-apache-poi-3-6/4274289#4274289

Comment: how to get to the formula type?

Comment: Why did you use `FormulaType.NAMEDRANGE`?  Shouldn't it be `FormulaType.CELL`?